# Почему не выводится картинка реакт-компонента?

Tags: css, reactjs

Написал такой код для фоновой картинки,сам блок исправен,потому что если написать ссылку на картинку в классе back,то она выводится.Все остальные пропсы компонент видит.

```
<div className="back" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.image})`}} >
```

Родитель:

```
import React from "react";



const Knopka_tovara = (props) => {
    return (

    <div id={props.id} className="knopka_tovara">
        <div className="goods_img">
            <div className="back" style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${props.image})`}} >
              
                <div className="check_like" >
                    <input  className="liked_check"type="checkbox"/>
                    
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div className="content_blok">
            <ul className="content">
                <li href="#" className="goods_name">{props.name}</li>
                <li href="#" className="price_and_desc"> 
                    <div className="p_d_blok">
                        <div className="desc">{props.desc}</div>
                        <div className="price"> {props.price} </div>
                    </div>   

                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="dinamic_korzina">
                <button className="korzina_v_tovare" data-key={props.id}>
                    Добавить в корзину
                </button>

        </div>
        
    </div>
    );



};

export default Knopka_tovara;
```

Родитель вложен сюда:

```
import React  from "react";
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import Knopka_tovara from "../components/knopka_tovara";
import {
    selectGoods
} from '../store/goodsSlice';

function GoodsList(){
    const goods = useSelector(selectGoods);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    

    return (
        <div className="tovari">
            {goods.map(item => <Knopka_tovara price={item.price} image={item.image} id={item.id} desc={item.desc}  name={item.name} key={item.id} />
                
         )}
        </div>
        
    );


}



export default GoodsList;
```

Comment: Добавьте код родительского компонента, чтобы мы видели, как именно вы передаёте картинку

Comment: Наверно потому что ковычек нет className="back" style={{"backgroundImage: url(${props.image})"}}> только на одинарные надо заменить

Comment: @Object417 добавил

Comment: @Arcadiy есть апострофные кавычки,они не отображаются почему то на сайте (вот такие ` ` )

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Просьба исправить вопрос и заменить картинку на код в текстовом формате. Для этого нажмите [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1372610/edit) под самим вопросом

Comment: @Dmitry Исправил,спасибо что показали как код нормально вкладывать

Comment: @Object417 Исправил вопрос,извините за беспокойство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта, как подгрузить картинку:

1. Разместить её в папке `public` и указать относительный путь как из папки `public`, т.е.:

```
public
- images
--  myImg1.jpg
- index.html
src
- App.js
- index.js

In any component:
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url("./images/myImg1.jpg")` }} />
```

2. Разместить картинку где-то в `src` и импортировать в нужный компонент. Путь указывать уже относительно папки с компонентом, т.е.:

```
src
- components
--  MyElem.js
- images
--  myImg1.jpg
- App.js
- index.js

In MyElem.js:
import myImg from "../images/myImg1.jpg"

<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url("${myImg}")` }} />
```

Comment: Спасибо,все работает!